# Display errors with PDFViewer on Android

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

Getting PDFViewer to work. Now I have black blocks on the pages. Looks like a rendering problem.

```java
PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
File pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+ "/Download/", "/epaper.pdf");
pdfView.fromFile(pdfFile).enableSwipe(true).swipeHorizontal(true).enableAnnotationRendering(true).load();
```

[image]

In Emulator it all works fine. I tried `bestQuality(true)`, but nothing changed.

My Phone: Xiaomi Mi 9 (if it helps)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this.

DarkMode needed to be deactivated in themes.xml:

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`

Only using:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

did not work.